# Can't get toupper to work with a vector

Tags: c++, vector, toupper

I'm working on an exercise to store words in a `<vector>` of `string`s, then convert all the letters to uppercase, and print out eight words per line. Everything works fine except the `toupper()` part of my code. Here it all is:

```
vector<string> words;
string theWords;
string word;

while(cin >> word)
    words.push_back(word);

for(auto &i : words) {
    word = i;
    for(auto &j: word)
        j = toupper(j);
}

int k = 0;
for(auto i : words) {
    cout << i << " ";
    ++k;
    if(k % 8 == 0)
        cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For the best responses to questions, you should always try and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/), what you expect the output/behavior to be and what you output/behavior you see instead. If you are having a compile error, please post the compiler error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I hadn't come across taht before. I will do so in the future, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing your new updated string in `word`, but you should be updating `i`

Change this

```
for(auto &i : words) {
    word = i;
    for(auto &j: word)    // word is updated, but your vector is not
        j = toupper(j);
}
```

... to this:

```
for (auto &i : words)      // for every string i in words vector
    for (auto &j : i)      // update your i, not word
        j = toupper(j);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are converting the temporary string, "word" to upper case, and then discarding it.

```
string word;

for(auto &i : words) {
    word = i; <<-- here
    for(auto &j: word)
        j = toupper(j);
}
```

What you need to do is

```
for(auto &i : words) {
    for(auto &j: i)
        j = toupper(j);
}
```

Live demo here: http://ideone.com/pwQBQr#

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party but here is a version without the extra loop.

```
for(auto &i : words)
    std::transform(i.begin(), i.end(), i.begin(), ::toupper);
```

Answer (score 0):

the expression `word = i` used the string copy constructor. The `word` is not the one in the vector.